# nativescript preview not working on android app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-playground

I use nativescript preview app in Android.When I scan QR code, the preview app always show Components, not the home page.I can not find any error from device.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try clearing app data, if issue still persists try reinstalling the Playground & Preview apps.

Comment: I reinstalled these apps but still no effect...